# Android: Which button was pressed

Tags: android, button

I found the following solution for detecting which of my buttons was pressed:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
    case R.id.bteins:
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "bzeins", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    t.show();
    break;
    case R.id.btzwei:
    // handle button B click;
    break;
    case R.id.btdrei:
        Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(this, "btdfrei", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        t1.show();
    break;
    case R.id.btvier:
    // handle button B click;
    break;
    default:
    throw new RuntimeException("Unknow button ID");
    }
    }
```

My problem is that when I press `bteins` or `btdrei` nothing happens. What´s my mistake?

Comment: You need to post a bit more code here to make it easier to answer your question. The error could be in the code that adds the `OnClickListener` to the buttons, or the button ids could be misspelled, etc... In general, it is better to do your research first and checking your program with a debugger before posting questions to SO

Comment: please show your activity code, full, so we can help you in a better way and as fast as possible.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement `onClick` for each button like this:

```
    findViewById(R.id.bteins).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //do some things!
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.btzwei).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //do some things!
        }
    });
....
```

or implement `OnClickListener` in activity and set all buttons click to that:

```
public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test);

        findViewById(R.id.bteins).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btzwei).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btdrei).setOnClickListener(this);
        findViewById(R.id.btvier).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        switch(v.getId())
            {
            case R.id.bteins:
                Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "bzeins", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                t.show();
                break;
            case R.id.btzwei:
                // handle button B click;
                break;
            case R.id.btdrei:
                    Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(this, "btdfrei", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t1.show();
                break;
            case R.id.btvier:
                // handle button B click;
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknow button ID");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `OnClickListener` to the button? I guess you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class theexample extends Activity implements OnClickListener

//OnCreateEvent
bteins.setOnClickListener(this);
btvier.setOnClickListener(this);

public void OnClick(View v){
switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bteins:
                Toast.makeText(this, "bzeins", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                t.show();
                break;
            case R.id.btzwei:
                // handle button B click;
                break;
            case R.id.btdrei:
                   Toast.makeText(this, "btdfrei", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.btvier:
                // handle button B click;
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknow button ID");
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect triggers to their respective handlers with `setOnClickListener()`

This method either gets `this` as a parameter, and than your activity has to implement OnClickListener (Eclipse can help you auto refactor these things easily.)

Or, just pass it a new OnClickListener on the spot:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(*buttons id*);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //You can check v attributes to see what was clicked as well. 
    }
});
```